# Java crashes on wav playback

Tags: java, audio, crash, clip

I am playing a .wav sound in Java. I have some code that looks like this:

```
package tools;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class ClipHandler implements LineListener {
    private Clip clip;

    public ClipHandler(Clip clip) {
        this.clip = clip;
        clip.addLineListener(this);
    }

    public void play() {
        clip.start();
    }

    public void update(LineEvent e) {
        if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            clip.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The method that gets called:

```
public static void play(String path) {
    try {
        URL soundUrl = SoundTools.class.getResource(path);
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundUrl);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
        new ClipHandler(clip).play();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I try to playback a .wav file. It always works the first time, but after a couple times of calling play(path), the window I am playing my game in freezes completely; it wont let me do anything. I need help! By the way, I call the code like this: `SoundTools.play(soundPath);`

Comment: Tell us more about your game, your window, your GUI library. Swing? And if so, are you respecting Swing threading rules?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes I am using Swing, and a little bit of awt. What else would you like to know?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions/errors/stack traces in the console, or is Java just freezing?

Comment: 99% chance you've got a Threading problem where you're likely inadvertently tying up the Swing event thread with your sound clips. 100% chance that we're not going to be able to help you based on the code you've posted. As @MadProgrammer recommends and which I second, isolate your problem by creating a small runnable example, an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that we can run, modify and help correct. Yes, this asking you to do some work for us, but it is work that is well worthwhile to do.

Answer (score 0):

after a gruesome search sprint all over the interwebs, I have found the answer!! What I needed was to run `clip.close()` in a new `Thread`. Why? I think this has to do with the fact that it takes time to close, but mine was freezing. Eh, it works! Here it is:

```
package tools;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class ClipHandler implements LineListener, Runnable {
    private Clip clip;

    public ClipHandler(Clip clip) {
        this.clip = clip;
        clip.addLineListener(this);
    }

    public void play() {
        clip.start();
    }

    public void update(LineEvent e) {
        if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            System.out.println("stopping!");
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        clip.close();
        System.out.println("stopped!");
    }
}
```

And the method (In the same package (If it isn't, import SoundTools)):

```
public static synchronized void play(String path) {
    try {
        URL soundUrl = SoundTools.class.getResource(path);
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundUrl);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
        new ClipHandler(clip).play();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope you all find this useful!
P.S. This works in .jars!